# MySQL Router cannot connect to MySQL after server restart

Tags: mysql

I have such a configuration:

3 MySQL Servers (v.5.7.17):

[A]. 192.168.0.10:3306

[B]. 192.168.0.20:3306

[C]. 192.168.0.30:3306

MySQL Router 2.1 (192.168.0.30:3308)

**[router.cnf]**

```
[DEFAULT]
plugin_folder  = /opt/mysql/router2.1.n/lib/mysqlrouter

[logger]
level = DEBUG

[routing]
bind_address = 192.168.0.30:3308
mode = read-write
destinations = 192.168.0.10:3306,192.168.0.20:3306,192.168.0.30:3306
```

MySQL router works fine if all servers are UP (alive).
But if we restart all the 3 servers (A,B,C) then MySQL Router says:

```
“Can’t connect to MySQL server”
```

Any idea?

P.S. In order to make it work again I have to restart MySQL Router so I am wondering whether MySQL Router can figure out it itself.

Comment: It seems that router service starts before MySql service.

Comment: Is it running on linux or windows?

Comment: CentOS 7.

Before MySQL servers restart I can use router to connect to any one but after I am getting “Can’t connect to MySQL server”.

Comment: According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-router/2.1/en/mysql-router-conf-options.html#option_mysqlrouter_mode "In read-write mode, all traffic is directed to the initial address on the list. If that fails, then MySQL Router will try the next entry on the list, and will continue trying each MySQL server on the list. If no more MySQL servers are available on the list, then routing is aborted. This method is also known as "first-available"."